# How can I run selenium tests in parallel with JS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests

I've been checking out https://theintern.github.io/. I have also looked at https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html.

I have found ways to run multiple suites in parallel with either system. However I have not found a way to run multiple tests within the same suite in parallel.

Does anyone know of a framework that allows this within JS? I know it's possible within Java, but haven't had much luck here.

Comment: CasperJS?  nightwatch.js?  Nemo.js?  DalekJS? etc.  etc.  There are probably a lot of frameworks I think.   Also, every JavaScript MVC framework, like Ember.js, usually has an associated multi-threaded automation tool (TestEM).  This question is a huge rabbit hole.

Comment: Yeah I know there are a lot of frameworks out there. I've checked two and both allow for running in parallel suites, but not tests. I was just hoping someone here would know which of the many can handle parallel tests.

Comment: PS: Sorry if that seemed terse, was trying to respond quickly while I was in a meeting

Comment: I don't mind. I'm not cranky like lots of people on here.

Comment: @djangofan all that aside, the multi-threaded automation i have seen is per suite/file. Are you saying one of those can multi-thread multiple tests in same file/suite?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know the answer to that.  I've seen demos of some of the frameworks but I have not heard of not being able to run parallel tests (not suites).  So, if its a asynchrynous limitation or something, I know not the answer.

Comment: @DaveStein did your research end in something useful? :) I am also interested in the same question right now.

Comment: @yashaka I usually put an answer to my own question if I do. I don't think I won out here other than better defining suites.